Why does Eric's talking to Em about his grandfather lead to a tense situation?
The protagonist of Anita Desai's The Zigzag Way, Eric, has accompanied his scientist girlfriend, Em, on a research field trip to Mexico. Eric realizes that his grandfather David had been a Cornish miner in Mexico, and that his grandmother Betty had died there after giving birth to his father, Paul. By profession, Eric is a researcher focused on immigration, so he decides to investigate his own family history. Em is skeptical, but Eric says that this line of inquiry might help him get purchase on his struggling research project:

"This could be just what I need — for my book," he announced, letting in the view of the plaza and the evening sky above it. He expected this reference to his "book" to make an impression on her if nothing else did. "I'd never thought my family could ever be of help — but they might have something to give. I'll have to find out."
This led to what was an evening of almost total silence and disappointment. They canceled their reservation at the Café Tacubaya and instead ate in the sepulchral hotel dining room, watched over by waiters in funereal uniform, talking, if at all, of travel agencies and banks and postal services; then they retired to lie at opposite sides of the so-called matrimonial bed, pretending to sleep.
Desai, Anita. The Zigzag Way. Boston: Houghton Mifflin, 2004. p. 33.

This seems like a non-sequitur? Em is aware that Eric has been facing writer's block. One would expect that she would be glad to hear about a new angle for his research. So why does Eric's mentioning this potential research angle lead to "an evening of almost total silence and disappointment?"
